# Eclipse won't start after choosing workspace path

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed the Eclipse IDE and started it, but when I got to choose my workspace path it gave me an error, I included the log file below.

**What I have tried**

Some solutions I found told me to run

> eclipse.exe -clean

but that didn't work. Another solution suggested to clean the `.snap` files, but there wheren't any. I also deleted the `/meta` folder, without success.

This is the log file mentioned above:

> !SESSION 2017-09-30 05:19:57.576
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20170906-1700 java.version=9 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-30 05:20:08.956 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    ... 25
>   more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-30 05:20:08.972
>   !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/annotation/PreDestroy   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot
>   be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    ... 21
>   more !SESSION 2017-09-30 05:28:12.431
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20170906-1700 java.version=9 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-30 05:28:36.887 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    ... 25
>   more
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-09-30 05:28:36.897
>   !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/annotation/PreDestroy   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot
>   be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    ... 21
>   more

Comment: Eclipse will not run with Java 9 without modifying the eclipse.ini

Comment: That is not what the duplicate tells you to do. Add the --add-modules lines after the -vmargs.

Comment: thank you so much.that worked!